# Есть ли конструктор у базовых типов?

Tags: c++

Есть ли конструктор у базовых типов, например int?

Comment: Нет. Это ведь не структуры/классы

Comment: а потом находится вот такой код `using Int = int;
int main(){
    Int a = 1;
    a.~Int();
}`

Comment: @KoVadim, непонятно, почему ваш пример вообще компилируется? Как можно вызывать деструктор у того, что не является классом? Какой эффект это производит? После вызова деструктора можно ли обращаться к переменной `a`?

Comment: @KoVadim, кажется понял - это [pseudo destructor call](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators): "Allowing pseudo destructor call makes it possible to write code without having to know if a destructor exists for a given type."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Но не в обычном понимании. У базовых типов в С++ есть тривиальные конструкторы по умолчанию, которые нельзя изменить.

Конструктор в обычном понимании (которые может определить программист) представляет из себя функцию-член для какого-либо класса. int и прочие базовые типы являются POD-типами (Plain Old Data - простая структура данных).
Здесь можно узнать больше про POD-типы: [POD типы в C++](http://itw66.ru/blog/c_plus_plus/470.html).

Относительно тривиальных конструктов - они описываются в этой статье на cpprefernce.com, в разделе, посвященном тривиальным конструкторам (Trivial constructor): [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). В частности, упоминается следующее (приведу перевод с английской версии, потому что русская версия cppreference очень сырая):

> Конструктор является тривиальным если соблюдаются следующие условия:
>
> - Конструктор не определяется пользователем (т.е. он неявно определяется компилятором)
>
> Тривиальным конструктором по умолчанию является конструктор, который не
> выполняет никаких действий. Все типы данных, совместимые с языком C (POD типов) имеют тривиальный конструктор по умолчанию.

Также в книге Бьярна Страуструпа "Принципы и практика с использованием C++" в главе 9 (посвященной конструкторам)  упоминается наличие у базовых классов конструкторов по умолчанию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то перевод у вас слишком вольный. 1) "The default constructor **for class `T`** is trivial (i.e. performs no action) if all of the following is true: ..." Здесь речь идёт про конструкторы классового типа и только классового типа. 2)  "All data types compatible with the C language (POD types) are trivially default-constructible." Здесь не сказано, что все POD-типы имеют конструктор, здесь сказано, что все POD-типы являются [DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible). Чтобы быть DefaultConstructible, не обязательно иметь конструктор.

Comment: Давайте разберемся, в случае чего отредактирую свой ответ. На странице  [Default constructors] (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) вижу, что 
"A **type** with a public default constructor is DefaultConstructible". Так же удалось найти цитату в книге Страуструпа, подтверждающую что у базовых классов присутствует конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: Ну да, тип с публичным конструктором по-умолчанию является DefaultConstructible, но это ведь ещё не означает, что DefaultConstructible тип обязательно имеет публичный конструктор по-умолчанию.

Comment: Конструкция вида `int a{};` называется [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Для классовых типов она приводит к вызову конструктора, но для скалярных типов (коим и является `int`) она приводит к [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). Эффект  zero initialization для скалярного типа - инициализация объекта нулевым значением. Обратите внимание, что для zero initialization также упоминаются конструкторы, но только для классовых типов.

Comment: Посмотрите [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131911/what-does-int-do-in-c) на en.stackoverflow.com: "`int` is not a class, and has no constructor.".

Comment: При всём уважении к Бьярне Страуструпу, его мнение в данном конкретном вопросе немного расходится со стандартом языка: [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors)

Comment: @Neilana Страуструп же в описании к книге пишет, что это учебное пособие, а не справочник и для полной точности нужно смотреть спецификацию. В данном случае спецификация четко ставит точку в вопросе - конструкторы прерогатива только классовых типов. Для других типов такого понятия как конструктор нет.

Answer (score 2):

**В C++ конструкторы и деструкторы имеют только классовые типы**.
Остальные типы не имеют ни конструкторов, ни деструкторов.
Но синтаксис языка, вкупе с правилами инициализации, позволяют использовать идентичные (или почти идентичные) конструкции инициализации как для классовых, так и для не классовых типов. Например, имеется такой синтаксис инициализации:

```
int x(10);//кажется, что это создание int с вызовом конструктора
```

Но в C++ для классовых и не классовых типов прописаны разные правила инициализации при одинаковом синтаксисе, приводящие к похожим результатам.
Просто представьте, что такой синтаксис бы отсутствовал. Возьмем шаблон:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T obj) {
   T obj2(obj1);
}

//...
foo(std::string(""));//ok
foo(10);//ошибка
```

Пришлось бы изобретать новое нечто, чтобы обойти проблему, коих и так хватает. Сейчас же такой код абсолютно законен, и будет приводить просто к использованию разных правил инициализации в зависимости от типа.
Тоже самое касается кода, приведенного @KoVadim в комментариях:

```
using Int = int; int main(){ Int a = 1; a.~Int(); }
```

он показывает еще одно из правил языка, позволяющее сгладить различия между  классовыми и не классовыми типами, в частности, в шаблонах. Если бы этого правила не было, пришлось бы городить дополнительные "костыли" для решения проблем с отсутствием деструктора у типа при явном его (деструкторе) вызове.

P.S. Не всё что плавает и крякает является уткой, и это очень хорошо показано в фильме "Особенности национальной охоты".